# How to issue "module load" in a shell or Perl script (i.e., non-interactively)

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, environment-modules

I can use the "module load xyz" command interactively, but when run from a script, it says it can't find the "module" command.  Is there any way of loading modules in a script?

Answer (score 4):

Start your bash script like this:

`#!/bin/bash -l`

Note that modules loaded after this with module load xyz will only be available from inside the script file.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
source /etc/profile
```

If that doesn't work, you most likely have a problem with aliases.  You may need

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

in your script.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but something like the below isn't working:

adm@mach:~> cat test1.sh
#!/bin/bash

source /etc/profile
shopt -s expand_aliases

module load MySQL

#do stuff with mysql
adm@mach:~> ./test1.sh
./test1.sh: line 6: module: command not found

Comment: <code>
adm@mach:~> cat test1.sh
#!/bin/bash

source /etc/profile
shopt -s expand_aliases

module load MySQL

#do stuff with mysql
adm@mach:~> ./test1.sh
./test1.sh: line 6: module: command not found
</code>

Comment: What about changing your first line to "/bin/bash -l"?

Answer (score -1):

If by modules you mean Linux kernel modules, look into `modprobe` (or the more low-level `insmod`).  There's usually no need to use whatever aliases (like `module`) that your Linux distro loaded into your shell.

(For example, I don't even have a `module` command on my distro/setup, so I can't try it to see what kind of modules you're referring to.)

Comment: catamount was talking about [Environment Modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_Modules_%28software%29)