# How to execute "load module X" in Perl

Tags: perl, command, system

I'm having problems loading a kernel module from Perl.

I have already tried:

```
system ("module load X");

system ´module load X´ 

exec(module load X);
```

It complains

```
Can't exec "module": No such file or directory
```

Comment: See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127383/how-to-issue-module-load-in-a-shell-or-perl-script-i-e-non-interactively

Comment: I have already checked this , the answers are given regrading bash scripting not Perl

Comment: uh, none of the snippets you gave give the output you said you got! Or any output at all, since you didn't do any error checking. Please fix up your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You *probably* want

```
use X;
```

But I guess that you should read some introductionary material on Perl if you're struggling why `system` or `exec` doesn't load a module.

Comment: X Its not a Perl module it is kernel modules

Comment: That would of course warrant to be meantioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The proper function is indeed `system`.

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw( system );
system("module load X");
```

(By using IPC::System::Simple's version, we don't have to do any error checking.)

If the kernel can't find `module`, it's because it's not in the PATH. You can either adjust the PATH or use the full path to the executable.

```
system("/path/to/module load X");
```

Of course, I'm assuming your command actually makes sense since I don't know anything about loading kernel modules. That might not be a fair assumption since you said `load module` in one place and `module load` in another. Double check the command.